# What is the best way to fill large region in gnuplot with transparent color?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot my result from verification with gnuplot. Now I am trying to draw unsafe region for this picture. The imagine shows below. Suppose unsafe set is `x > 3`, then everything above `x = 3` should be filled with transparent colour to indicate it is an unsafe region. I am new to gnuplot, and I am thinking to draw a large rectangle with transparent colour, but is there a better way to achieve this in gnuplot? Thank you.

[image: Link for my current result]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, drawing a rectangle is a good option for your use case:

```
set object rectangle from graph 0, first 3 to graph 1, graph 1 fillcolor rgb 'red' fillstyle transparent solid 0.5 noborder 
plot ...
```

Using the `graph` coordinates makes three borders of your rectangle independent of the axes ranges.